# Missing PySide2 module error using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm trying to convert a python script to an executable with pyinstaller (version 4.8). The script has a GUI made through PySide2 which seems to be where the error occurs.

I tested my issue further on the following code, which seems to work as a MRE.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

And my input to pyinstaller is

```
pyinstaller --onefile pyside2test.py
```

When I try to run the .exe, I briefly get an error message saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'` before the command prompt running the exe terminates. I can also see the following line in the warn-myfile.txt file from the build directory: `missing module named PySide2`

The MRE seems to throw the same error message, although it's too brief for me to properly read it before termination, and the warn-file contains the same line regarding PySide2.

In the command prompt, I see that the PySide2 hook doesn't load, and I've tried various iterations of manually adding hooks or setting explicit paths or hidden imports (which I don't think is the correct way to go, as I explicitly import submodules from PySide2 in the file):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths=C:\mydir\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks pyside2test.py
```

and

```
pyinstaller --onefile --paths=C:\mydir\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\ pyside2test.py
```

and

```
pyinstaller --onefile --additional-hooks-dir=C:\mydir\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks pyside2test.py
```

About my installation of PySide2: `PySide2 version 5.13.2` channel `conda-forge`.

Potentially relevant system info from running pyinstaller:

```
3709 INFO: Python: 3.8.12 (conda)
3766 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18363-SP0
```

I hope this gives all the relevant information necessary for figuring out where I've gone wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you installed pyinstaller OR PySide outside the anaconda environment?

Comment: I can't believe it, but it does indeed seem to be the case that I had installed pyinstaller outside the anaconda environment. And that that was at fault. You're an absolute star. I was going a little mad there for a hot minute. Thank you!